# How to retrieve data from multiple checkbox which is built from .cs file with newCell.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I'm new at C# and I'm trying to retrieve data from multiple checkbox and I built it from .cs file with C# code.

These are the codes

```
newCell.Text += "<table id=\"CheckBoxList1\" class=\"checkboxlist\"><tbody>";
newCell.Text += "<tr><td>";
newCell.Text += "<input class=\"styled\" id=\"CheckBoxList1_0\" type=\"checkbox\" 
value=\"Value\" name=\"CheckBoxList1$\"></input>";
newCell.Text += "<label for=\"CheckBoxList1_0\">Text</label></td></tr>";
newCell.Text += "</tbody></table>";
```

There are 2 datas in database and I fetch them using these codes. I want to retrieve data(s) to TextBox which checkbox is selected.

Thank you

Comment: Are you creating the checkbox with textbox dynamically or fixed number of checkbox with textbox?

Comment: I'm fetching id from database and if the id is equal to 2 I create CheckBoxList and store it into table with these codes dynamically. Now I want to retrieve datas and send it to TextBoxes which checkboxes are selected.

Comment: I see, now. The "to retrieve datas" your saying which will be send to textbox to display maybe, where do you want to retrieve data from? Database? Value from the checkbox? Somewhere else?

Comment: Actually, I fetched datas from database using LINQ to SQL and I checked the datas if the data is equal to 1 or 2 or 3 etc. and I specified the input type according to data which came from database. For ex. if(datacamefromdb == 2){ I use checkbox to list items to provide user to choose one of them} OR if(datacamefromdb == 1){ I use TextBox to let user fill }. I used Request.Form to retrieve datas and there is no problem now. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the post back data exist on the `Request.Form` and to get one of them you use the `name` parameter of your control, in your case:

```
Request.Form["CheckBoxList1$"]
```

When you have a dynamic named control from asp.net you use the `UniqueID` of the control, as:

```
Request.Form[ControlID.UniqueID]
```

or in most case the asp.net is control the post back data and add it to some value of the control, eg on TextBoxes, the `.Text` keep the data.

Comment: Thank you Aristos, I made it and working successfully.